# How to call table.reloadData by didReceiveData() in session using Multipeer Connectivity (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, multipeer-connectivity

I am struggling on a problem that when I receive data from session using Multipeer Connectivity framework, I want to update the data and reload the table of a view controller instantly.

Here are my codes for didReceiveData function of MPCHandler:

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    NSLog("%@", "didReceive: \(data)")
    if var dict: [NSDictionary] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [NSDictionary]{
        let d = dict.removeFirst()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.winnerDataController.syncWinnerFromDictionary(d: dict)

    }
}
```

For sync function in WinnerDataController

```
func syncWinnerFromDictionary(d: NSDictionary){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Winner", in: context)!

    let winner: Winner = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: context) as! Winner
    winner.setValue(d.value(forKey: "index"), forKey: "index")
    winner.setValue(d.value(forKey: "dept"), forKey: "dept")
    winner.setValue(d.value(forKey: "name"), forKey: "name")
    save()
    appDelegate.resultViewController.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I want to update and reload the table of resultViewContoller upon the receive of the data. However, when it goes to `appDelegate.resultViewController.tableView.reloadData()`, the console gives out `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. I spent all day on figuring why the tableView is nil, yet still haven't got any ideas.

Could someone plz help. Thx

I tried the following codes as provided by @Hitesh Sultaniya: `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testing), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "syncWinner"), object: nil)` and `func testing(notification: Notification){
        print("testing")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }` in result view controller. Also, `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "syncWinner"), object: nil)` in WinnerDataController.

In the console, "testing" is printed. However, after a few seconds, 
"This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes"
is shown.

Then, I tried this:

```
func testing(notification: Notification){
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async{
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

}

Now, no error is shown. But the table is still not yet reloaded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In resultViewController you can set Notification observer to reload tableview

you can set in this manner

// Register and add observer in result view controller

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reloadTableView(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "<Your Notfication Name>"), object: nil)

 // handle notification
 func reloadTableView(_ notification: NSNotification) {

  //relaod your table view 
 }
```

And when you are done with receiving data you can post notification like this

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(notificationName, object: nil)
```

So this will post notification that you have set in result view controller and then your task will be performed

Note : This is just pseudo code so might contain error

If you application making UI changes that where you make UI changes while performing this task 
***And I think you will also need to fetch data from database again before reloading table view because as per your code that you have provided in question you directly reloading table.*** 
You can check for current thread like this,

```
 if (Thread.isMainThread == true)
 {
                    //Perform UI Task 
 }
 else
 {
      //Dispatch for main queue with synchronous not asynchronous and then update the UI
 }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Hitesh Sultaniya, I solved the problem.

Here are my codes which work:

For sync function in WinnerDataController:

```
func syncWinnerFromDictionary(d: NSDictionary){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Winner", in: context)!
    let winner: Winner = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: context) as! Winner
    winner.setValue(d.value(forKey: "index"), forKey: "index")
    winner.setValue(d.value(forKey: "dept"), forKey: "dept")
    winner.setValue(d.value(forKey: "name"), forKey: "name")
    save()
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "syncWinner"), object: nil)
```

For ResultViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testing), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "syncWinner"), object: nil)
    appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }

func testing(notification: Notification){
    if Thread.isMainThread == true{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print("main thread")
    }
    else{
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.updateList()
            print(winnerList.count)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("not main thread")

        }
    }
```

Initially, I tried this in ResultViewController but doesn't work

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testing), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "syncWinner"), object: nil)
    appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    }

func testing(notification: Notification){
    if Thread.isMainThread == true{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print("main thread")
    }
    else{
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("not main thread")

        }
    }
```

It is because when it runs the block of DispatchQueue.main.sync, it is not the main thread and hasn't got the most updated winnerList. In fact, the table has been reload yet with outdated winnerList. Therefore, it seems like table not yet reloaded.

Then, I added `self.updateList()` to let this thread get the most updated core data. Finally, it works.

Hope this would be helpful for those who struggle with the same problem as I did.